# ldap_bind: Invalid Credentials (49)

Tags: openldap

I'm running **OpenLDAP 2.4-28** on **XUBUNTU 12.04.**

I'm reading *"Mastering OpenLDAP"* and configuring along with the book.

When I try to perform the following search (page 47):

```
$ ldapsearch -x -W -D 'cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com' -b "" -s base
```

I am prompted for the password. Then I enter "secret" but I get the following error:

```
ldap_bind: Invalid Credentials (49).
```

The following is my `slapd.conf`:

```
# slapd.conf - Configuration file for LDAP SLAPD
##########
# Basics #
##########
include /etc/ldap/schema/core.schema
include /etc/ldap/schema/cosine.schema
include /etc/ldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
pidfile /var/run/slapd/slapd.pid
argsfile /var/run/slapd/slapd.args
loglevel none
modulepath /usr/lib/ldap
# modulepath /usr/local/libexec/openldap
moduleload back_hdb

##########################
# Database Configuration #
##########################
database hdb
suffix "dc=example,dc=com"
rootdn "cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com"
rootpw secret
directory /var/lib/ldap
# directory /usr/local/var/openldap-data
index objectClass,cn eq

########
# ACLs #
########
access to attrs=userPassword
    by anonymous auth
    by self write
    by * none
access to *
    by self write
    by * none
```

and here is the ldap.conf:

```
# LDAP Client Settings
URI ldap://localhost
BASE dc=example,dc=com
BINDDN cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com
SIZELIMIT 0
TIMELIMIT 0
```

Comment: somewhat related: http://wiki.openiam.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=7635198

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this @alibaba? I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't see an obvious problem with the above.

It's *possible* your `ldap.conf` is being overridden, but the command-line options will take precedence, `ldapsearch` will ignore `BINDDN` in the main `ldap.conf`, so the only parameter that could be wrong is the URI.
(The order is `ETCDIR/ldap.conf` then `~/ldaprc` or `~/.ldaprc` and then `ldaprc` in the *current* directory, though there environment variables which can influence this too, see `man ldapconf`.)

Try an explicit URI:

```
ldapsearch -x -W -D 'cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com' -b "" -s base -H ldap://localhost
```

or prevent defaults with:

```
LDAPNOINIT=1 ldapsearch -x -W -D 'cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com' -b "" -s base
```

If that doesn't work, then some troubleshooting (you'll probably need the full path to the `slapd` binary for these):

- make sure your `slapd.conf` is being used and is correct (as root)

  > `slapd -T test -f slapd.conf -d 65535`

  You *may* have a left-over or default `slapd.d` *configuration directory* which takes preference over your `slapd.conf` (unless you specify your config explicitly with `-f`, `slapd.conf` is officially deprecated in OpenLDAP-2.4). If you don't get several pages of output then your binaries were built *without* debug support.
- stop OpenLDAP, then manually start `slapd` in a separate terminal/console with debug enabled (as root, ^C to quit)

  > `slapd -h ldap://localhost -d 481`

  then retry the search and see if you can spot the problem (there will be a lot of schema noise in the start of the output unfortunately). (Note: running `slapd` without the `-u`/`-g` options can change file ownerships which can cause problems, you should usually use those options, *probably* `-u ldap -g ldap` )
- if debug is enabled, then try also

  > `ldapsearch -v -d 63 -W -D 'cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com' -b "" -s base`